# I am getting module not found error for xlsxwriter in my executable file .What can be the issue and how can it be resolved?

Tags: python, powershell, executable, scheduler, xlsxwriter

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\somya\Downloads\Main-version1_Simran.py", line 22, in <module> from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'`

Above mentioned error i am getting while running my executable file.
I have used pyinstaller in powershell and cmd both to make this .exe file from python script.

But through conda prompt if i am making my executable file then i am not getting this error but it takes more to time to convert into .exe file.

I have tried to uninstall and intall the module too.
i believe there might be some missing package or file which i am not getting.

I want to schedule my script so its failing to run .
Kindly help if you understand my issue.

Thank you

Comment: Try add “import xlsxwriter” before the import line where the error occurs. That may help the packager include the files it needs.

Comment: @jmcnamara I have added that in my script